# PyQt6 - Highlight certain strings in a QLineEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a QLineEdit that acts as a command line

I want certain words to have a different color within the line

All of these words would end with a colon (":"), followed by the respective command. The prefix is just passing an argument.

```
help:
search:
run:
```

etc....

Is there a way to detect certain words and change their text color?

If the logic has to be "everything containing ':' changes color", that's fine

If the logic has to be "the color change effects all chars, not just specific words", that's fine also.

I just have no idea how to implement this. [If 'word' in focused QLine, change 'word' color]

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Look through the documentation in terms of how to return the contents of the QLineEdit as a string (I believe something like toPlainText()). In terms of changing the color I suggest using simple HTML markup, that's how I've been able to do it in the past. There is a more complex way using cursors and such, but for simple cases like this HTML should work fine. And lastly to find the colons I suggest python's re module (regex).

Comment: @Spencer Thanks for the suggestion - could you share how you were able to do this? Styling PyQt via html/css is very new to me.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed you specified `QLinEdit`. What you're going to want is a `QTextEdit`, which will allow you to do multiple lines and work with the text more easily. `QTextEdit` by default interprets HTML markup as a web browser would, so you an for example use a `<span>` tag with a color attribute and it should just work.

Comment: I'm unable to right now but if I can get around to it later tonight I'll see if I can throw something simple together to illustrate.

Comment: If you can put together a code sample it would be helpful.

Comment: @Spencer Bless your heart - take your time, my friend. I appreciate it. All my lines use QLineEdit; is it a monumental task to convert all these over?

Comment: QLineEdit doesn't provide such support. Use QTextEdit with a QSyntaxHighlighter, do some research, as there are various resources on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it sounds like what you really want is a `QTextEdit`, which will allow you to do text formatting similar to a [webpage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#using-qtextedit-as-a-display-widget). If you for some reason really do want a `QLineEdit`, I would subclass a `QTextEdit` to make it look and behave like a `QLineEdit` (I have done this pretty simply before, however that is a different topic).

Next, it seems your question is actually twofold. The first question is how to color specific pieces of text, which I will answer below. The second is how to find said pieces text, to which I suggest looking into the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module in python. If that is above your current knowledge you can pretty easily implement it just using the good old `string.replace()` function, which would only be a bit less robust. Looking at my sample code it should be clear where that would be done, I'll let you implement it yourself as it is fairly simple and just requires some doc reading and trial and error ;)

Here's a pretty minimal example showing how I would implement the `QTextEdit`:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
d.setLayout(l)

# construct the text edit
edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
edit.setText('help:<br>search:<br>run:<br>')
l.addWidget(edit)

# parse the text and add formatting. This could also be made into a function which gets called by a signal such as edit.editingFinished()
text = edit.toPlainText()
new_text = ''
for line in text.split('\n'):
    new_text += '<span style="color: red">' + line + '</span><br>'
edit.setText(new_text) # put it back to the text edit

d.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```